# To Automatically Add Language to Book instance when Book is selected

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to Show Language of Book In Each BookInstance Table?
How Do i do it. Please Guide me
Everything Else is Working Fine.

Here is the code :-

Modals.py

[Modals.py](https://codeshare.io/WdDm0E)

Admin.py

[Admin.py](https://codeshare.io/EB861N)

Note :- i am new to django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class AdminBookInstance(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = BookInstance
    list_display = ('book' , 'due_back' , 'status' , 'cover' , 'id', 'language')
    list_filter = ('book' , 'due_back' , 'status' , 'cover' , 'id', 'book__language__language_name')
    def language(self, obj):
        data = list(obj.book.language.filter(book=obj.book).values_list("language_name", flat=True))
        return data


admin.site.register(BookInstance, AdminBookInstance)
```

Comment: Its Working Perfectly Fine. Could you please Explain your Solution , so i can understand it. I am unable to understand

Comment: take a look in [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) . `ManyToManyField fields aren’t supported, because that would entail executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add that method’s name to list_display. (See below for more on custom methods in list_display.)`
You can also define that function in models. and use that in `list_display`

Comment: If i dont use ManytoMany Fields then, which method should i use.

Comment: you can use `obj.fk_name` directly without defining new custom method if you use `ForeignKey`.